# Is the file position per inode?

Tags: c, linux

I am confused with the concept of file position as used in lseek. Is this file position maintained at inode level or a simple variable which could have different values for different process working on the same file?

Comment: Since you said inode, I infer you are speaking about Linux/Unix.  But could you add the OS to make this clear.  I think OS might matter on the answer.  One note:  I suspect what is going on is per file descriptor (a higher level than inode).  So if you have multiple file descriptors for one file, this could be happening

Comment: And if you have duped a file descriptor, this definitely might set up a scenario where you'd see this problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Per the [lseek docs](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/lseek.2.html), the file position is associated with the open file pointed to by a file descriptor, i.e. the thing that is handed to your by [open](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/open.2.html). Because of functions like `dup` and `fork`, multiple *descriptors* can point to a single *description*, but it's the description that holds the location cursor.

Think about it: if it were associated with the inode, then you would not be able to have multiple processes accessing a file in a sensible manner, since all accesses to that file by one process would affect other processes.

Thus, a single process could have track many different file positions as it has file descriptors for a given file.

Comment: File position is associated with an *open file description*, not a file descriptor. Many different file descriptors can refer to the same open file description, due to `fork`, `dup`, etc.

Comment: Thank you for adding link to open. it actually describes that file position is part of the entry referenced by the file descriptor.

Answer (score 1):

It's not an 'inode', but FILEHANDLE inside kernel.

Inode is a part of file description of the *nix specific file system on the disk. FAT32, for example, has no inodes, but supported by Linux.

Answer (score 0):

For know the relation between file descriptors and open files, we need to examine three data structures.

- the per-process file descriptor table
- the system wide table of open file descriptors
- the file system i-node table.

For each process kernel maintains a table of open file descriptors. Each entry in this table records information about a single file descriptor including

- a set of flags controlling the operation of the file descriptor.
- a reference to the open file description

The kernel maintains a system wide table of all open file descriptors. An open file description stores all information related to an open file including:

- the current file offset(as updated by read() and write(),or explicitly modified using lseek())
- status flags specified when opening the file.
- the file access mode (read-only,write only,or read-write,as specified in open())
- setting relating to signal-driven I/O and
- a reference to i-node object for this file.

> *Reference-Page 94,The Linux Programming Interface by Michael Kerrisk*